# Java socket message arrives order

Tags: java, sockets

I would like to write a socket program...

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",12345);
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
output.writeUTF("Hello");
output.writeUTF("World");
 ...
 ...
```

"Hello", "World"...which string get arrived first?
Did socket guarantees the order?

Comment: If it's a TCP socket, yes it's guaranteed. But for Datagram(UDP) socket is't not.

Comment: @MM. you should add it as answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TCP protocol guarantees that all messages are sent completely and in-order. So you can rely on the premise that the "World" will always arrive after the "Hello". Should the "Hello" packet get lost for some reason, the delivery of the "World" packet to the other application will be delayed while the "Hello" packet is re-requested again.

This is handled automatically by the network stacks of the operating systems of the involved hosts - you don't have to do anything for that as an application programmer.

For more information about how the TCP protocol works, I can recommend you [the wikipedia article about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol).

When you use an UDP socket, on the other hand, the situation is differently. UDP does not guarantee sequence or reliability, so it might be possible that one packet overtakes the other (so the user receives the "World" before the "Hello"), or even that one gets lost (the user only receives "Hello" or only "World").

The standard [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class, however, uses TCP by default. This can be overridden by telling it to use UDP in the constructor by passing `true` as a third parameter (which is deprecated), or when you passed a custom socket implementation to the static method [Socket.setSocketImplFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSocketImplFactory%28java.net.SocketImplFactory%29) which uses UDP (which would be insane - the purpose of this method is to implement exotic transport layer protocols which are neither UDP nor TCP).

Usually, UDP sockets are represented by the class [DatagramSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html).